# Как собрать все письма почты в win-rar архив?

Tags: email, архивация

У меня есть почты на различных сервисах. Я везде поискал кнопку типа `скачать почту в архиве win-rar` - ни на одном популярном сервисе нет такой кнопки.
При этом, когда взламывают почту какому-нибудь видному деятелю, её заливают на сайты в виде **rar\zip** архива.

**Вопрос:** какие есть способы сбора и конвертации писем почты в rar\zip архив?

Comment: дык, получить её по IMAP из ящика, сохранить в любом удобном виде и заархивировать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer А статейку не кините, как это сделать?

Comment: гм... даже не знаю, на что дать ссылку... нужно просто выбрать любой почтовый клиент — гуёвый (например [thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net)) или консольный (например [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/)), настроить, то как он будет получать почту (у каждого провайдера обычно есть своя страница с настройками, например [gmail'овская](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229)). Как именно сохранять локально и экспортировать почту — зависит от клиента; один из самых простых форматов — [mbox](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox). для архивации файлов инструкции, думаю, не нужны...